# How to get the original and current values of navigational properties of an entity that is in modified state?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Let's say I have two tables like so:

```
Category
---------
Id
Name

Expense
---------------
Id
Name
CategoryId
Amount
```

If someone changes the details of an expense through the UI, how do I get the details of the old and new values of the expense's Category?

I have this so far in the `ObjectContext` class.

```
public override int SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
{
    foreach (var entry in ObjectStateManager
            .GetObjectStateEntries(
            System.Data.EntityState.Modified))
    {
      if (entry.Entity is Expense)
      {
        var oldName = entry.OriginalValues["Name"];

        var newName = entry.CurrentValues["Name"];

        Debug.Print(
         string.Format(
            "The name of an expense changed from '{0}' to '{1}'", 
            oldName, newName));

        // How do I get the old and new values of the Expense
        // entity's relations/navigational properties
        // such as the old and new values of 
        // Expense.Category.Name?
      }
    }

    return base.SaveChanges(options);
}
```

**Clarification:**

I must add that I know how to get those properties anyway *using another context*, i.e. by finding the `entry.Entity` in a new `ObjectContext` instance and then loading navigational properties of the Expense object in the new `ObjectContext` instance.

My question is -- is it possible to do that without loading up a new context? Is it possible to use just the `ObjectStateEntry` object to read non-scalar/navigational property values of the `ObjectStateEntry.Entity` object?